# How to add in- and -out transition effect to multiple modals at once using CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, transition

First post, so hopefully it is clear enough.

I have been tasked to create a modal object that overlays a multi-column/-row grid layout on a page. The modal should appear on hover of a particular grid item. When the modal appears, the background of the grid area only should dim. I was asked not to use any additionally libraries (e.g., jQuery).

To complete this task, I added two modal objects, one for the actual modal window and the other for the dimmer object. I could not get the CSS hover to work for both objects on the hover of the item in question, so I used JavaScript to add the CSS changes.

The transition effect works for the transition in but not the transition out. I assume I am overthinking this task so appreciate any suggestions.

```
<style type="text/css">

    .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .column {
        background-color: hsl(0,80%,70%);
    }

    #modal_maker {
        font-size: 5vw;
        height: 100%; 
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #modal_maker, #modal {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #modal {
        visibility: hidden;

        background-color: hsl(200,50%,70%);

        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;

        position: absolute;

        margin: auto;

        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    #background-dimmer {
        visibility: hidden;

        background-color: black;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        position: absolute;

        z-index: 1;

        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.5s;
    }

</style>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column" id="modal_maker">Hover Here</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>

    <div id="modal"></div>
    <div id="background-dimmer"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("mouseover", function(el) {
        if (el.target.id=="modal_maker" || el.target.id=="modal") {

            document.getElementById("modal").style.cssText = "visibility:visible; opacity: 1;"
            document.getElementById("background-dimmer").style.cssText = "visibility:visible; opacity: 0.75;"
        } else {
            document.querySelectorAll("#modal, #background-dimmer").forEach(x => x.style.cssText="opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;")
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Its not perfect... but it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all because of `visibility:hidden`

in js

```
...
} else {
        document.querySelectorAll("#modal, #background-dimmer").forEach(x => x.style.cssText="opacity: 0; visibility:hidden;")
}
...
```

in instant way you change `opacity` to `0` but also `visibility:hidden` so there is no time for transition, right away when code fires element is hiding.

You use `cssText` to change properties of element so `visibility:visible` won't be there when you move mouse on the other element, instead there will be `visibility:hidden` from the css(so you need to delete that also).

I know that it casues `#modal` to capture mouseover event then... thats the problem to figure out

I don't know if this solution is on purpose to hide modal when you `mouseover` other element only, what if I will leave mouse entirely from the table, the modal will stay... just wanted to mention maybe its not relevent.

I made fiddle based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/svh6dpfk/1/

One idea to fix this #modal capturing event is adding proper visibility as a callback(there is `transitionend` event which will capture moment when animation is done, so something like this would help:

```
document.querySelector("#modal, #background-dimmer").addEventListener("transitionend", function(el) {

  if(parseFloat(el.target.style.opacity) > 0){
    el.target.style.cssText = "visibility:visible;opacity:1";
    alert("animation end visible");
  }else{
    el.target.style.cssText = "visibility:hidden;opacity:0";
    alert("animation end unvisible");
  }

});
```

## Update

**it does work right now for me...**

its a bit tricky, your css needs to have `visibility:hidden` for modal and background-dimmer(like your code has)
this seems to work for me:

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("mouseover", function(el) {
    if (el.target.id=="modal_maker" || el.target.id=="modal") {

        document.getElementById("modal").style.cssText = "visibility:visible;opacity: 1;"
        document.getElementById("background-dimmer").style.cssText = "visibility:visible;opacity: 0.75;"
    } else {
        if(document.getElementById("modal").style.opacity == "1"){
        document.querySelectorAll("#modal, #background-dimmer").forEach(x => x.style.cssText="visibility:visible;opacity: 0; ")
        }
        /* alert("should be on leave") */;
    }
})
```

this part `.forEach(x => x.style.cssText="visibility:visible;opacity: 0; ")` changes because your css has always `visibility:hidden`, so you need to perform transition always on `visible`.

full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Loary65w/1/

you need to remember to have cross browser support you need to cover all those events
`webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend`

Hope it helps. Maybe there is better solution much simpler and I overcomplicated that one :F

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. The explanation is really helpful, and obviously the solution works!

Comment: @J.Dickstein if so :) then please accept my answer. I will gain some points :D

Comment: @J.Dickstein or propably you are searching for another answer... ;] if so please post, I am curious

Comment: sorry about that. As this was my first post, I didn't know how to accept. I provided an upvote, but didn't know I also needed to hit the check. Thanks again!